# How to configure SVN with ColdFusion Builder?

Tags: coldfusion, tortoisesvn, coldfusionbuilder

Can I configure ColdFusion Builder with SVN? Is there any in built functionality or do we need to use some external plugin?

I have gone through this link, [ColdFusion Builder 2 and the Subversive Plugin](http://www.trunkful.com/index.cfm/2011/7/11/ColdFusion-Builder-2-and-the-Subversive-Plugin), but it is also not working. Any suggestions please.

Comment: Deepak, It will be good if you can add some extra detail about why it is failing?

Comment: @PriteshPatel: Now i have successfully configured. But can you please suggest me how can i configure svn with an existing project in my workspace

Comment: I have better luck with http://subclipse.tigris.org/.  Maybe you can try that.

Comment: check out this: http://www.trunkful.com/index.cfm/2011/7/11/ColdFusion-Builder-2-and-the-Subversive-Plugin